# Can I plug in external hard drive into a dedicated NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, hard-drive

I just got a external solid state drive that supports usb 3.0.

Unfortunately, my computers doesn't support usb 3.0. But, my network is hooked up with gigabit lan. Is it possible to plug that external solid state drive into a nas (such as the [ts-419p](http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=127)).

By doing this, I can access my solid state drive at a gigabit lan speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most NAS devices (including the one you linked to) only support USB2, so there would be no advantage in doing this.

You could purchase an add-in card for your PC that supports USB3:

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Accessories/PCIE_USB3/

Attaching an SSD to a NAS would be a waste of the SSD.

Comment: What about if i plugged it into the ts-459?

http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_hardware.asp?p_id=165

This one supports usb 3.0. I have to use macintosh so using an adapter won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Theoretically if you connect to it with an iSCSI initiator, and configure Round-Robin MPIO correctly (if the unit supports that) with two LAN ports from your machine on a dedicated network, you'll see speeds approaching 2Gbps which is about 250Mb/s. USB3 operates at about 4.5Gbps or ~550Mb/s. Still not going to reach the speed of plugging it into that expansion card. Also, round-trip latency between your PC and the NAS will likely slow things down further.